# Cross import in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, socket.io

I´m making a node.js project in typescript. I want to put my socket.io code in a separate file to organize.
I see in the console that socketHandling.ts is loaded before index.ts, which I find odd.

But the problem is that Typeof server in socketHandling.ts is undefined.

**How do I make sure the server variable from index.ts is defined before socketHandling.ts is executed?**

*index.ts*

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as path from "path";
import * as socketHandle from "./socketHandling";
console.log("index.ts loaded");

export const server = express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../public")))
  .set("views", path.join(__dirname, "../../views"))
  .set("view engine", "ejs")
  .get("/*", httpGet)
  .post("/*", httpPost)
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));

socketHandle.initSockets();
```

*socketHandling.ts*

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { server } from "./index";
console.log("socketHandling.ts loaded");

console.log(server);
const io = new Server(server);

export function initSockets(): void {
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(`Client connected ${socket.id}`);
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log(`Client disconnected ${socket.id}`);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does it go through socketHandling before the index server is defined?

If index.ts is your entry point, once the program counter reaches line 3 of index.ts, the import will make it start executing socketHandling.ts, which contains another import back to index.ts, which wasn't even done executing yet.  So this looks like a circular import maybe you should avoid the situation altogether.

Proposed Solution:
Avoid the circular import by passing in the server from the top into the initSockets method that you import from the library file.

Try the following refactor:

index.ts

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as path from "path";
import * as socketHandle from "./socketHandling";
console.log("index.ts loaded");

export const server = express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../public")))
  .set("views", path.join(__dirname, "../../views"))
  .set("view engine", "ejs")
  .get("/*", httpGet)
  .post("/*", httpPost)
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));

socketHandle.initSockets(server);
```

socketHandling.ts

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
console.log("socketHandling.ts loaded");

let io: Server;

export function initSockets(server): void {
  if (!io) {
      io = new Server(server);
  }
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(`Client connected ${socket.id}`);
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log(`Client disconnected ${socket.id}`);
    });
  });
}
```

Typically it wont be sustainable to export stuff from your application entry point for the entire library to use.  Usually you see these kinds of variables passed down into methods rather than globally referenced across different files throughout the entire application.